# How do I map http_path in zipkin to AWS XRay request URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, trace, zipkin, aws-xray

I send my traces to Zipkin and I can tell I am setting the HTTP Path
[image]

But it does not map to XRay's Request URL.
[image]

Where can I do the mapping?

I am using the following images as per [my answer on integrating Spring Cloud Sleuth with Amazon X-Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66345419/242042)

- amazon/aws-xray-daemon:latest
- ghcr.io/openzipkin/zipkin-aws:latest

Looking through the code, I am using `HttpTracing` from ZipKin brave libraries I am presuming that's what it is using to populate the data.

Digging around some more there seems to be an [openzipkin/zipkin-aws#58](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-aws/issues/58) which sort of describes the issue

Comment: Hello, the request URL exists in the `http.request.url` field of an X-Ray seegment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-segmentdocuments.html#api-segmentdocuments-http

I'm not familiar with how Zipkin populates X-Ray segment data, but it appears to only be setting an annotation on the segment, which are treated as arbitrary key-value pairs and not actually read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through [the code](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-aws/blob/5c73661158841a2fc90d21bfa1ac8c14a6587ede/storage/xray-udp/src/main/java/zipkin2/storage/xray_udp/UDPMessageEncoder.java#L124-L137) I may just need to alter the default tracing to add the additional details.  Adding the following bean will make it configure to contain the necessary details.

```
@Bean
public HttpTracing httpTracing(Tracing tracing) {

    return HttpTracing.newBuilder(tracing)
        .serverRequestParser(
            (req, context, span) -> {
                HttpRequestParser.DEFAULT.parse(req, context, span);
                HttpTags.URL.tag(req, context, span);
            }
        )
        .serverResponseParser(
            ((response, context, span) -> {
                HttpResponseParser.DEFAULT.parse(response, context, span);
                HttpTags.STATUS_CODE.tag(response, span);
            })
        )
        .clientRequestParser(
            (req, context, span) -> {
                HttpRequestParser.DEFAULT.parse(req, context, span);
                HttpTags.URL.tag(req, context, span); // add the url in addition to defaults
            }
        )
        .clientResponseParser(
            ((response, context, span) -> {
                HttpResponseParser.DEFAULT.parse(response, context, span);
                HttpTags.STATUS_CODE.tag(response, span);
            })
        )
        .build();

}
```